# MySQL I/O error

Tags: mysql

I get the following error:

```
Can't create table 'tmp' (errno: 5) CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tmp
```

When trying to read the directory with the data files I get the following:

```
ls: reading directory .: Input/output error
```

In mysql:

```
mysql> show tables;
Empty set (0.28 sec)
```

But ...

```
mysql> select * from nw_site LIMIT 0,1;
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

So even though there's an I/O error, SELECTs and UPDATEs are working. The website still seems to be working.

mysqldump unfortunately can't get any data out, which means I don't have a backup - just 3 days of empty mysqldumps. As the site is working OK, I've only just noticed.

Any ideas how to proceed? I'd love to get a backup somehow.

** Edit **

I've found a way to get a backup without mysqldump:
http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=149869

Comment: You might have a bad hard drive sector.  It could have gone bad after you loaded the database into RAM.  If you reboot, it may not work at all.  I recommend backing up (since your `SELECT` still works) and try it on another machine.  Or at least FDISK.

Comment: Thanks. I was wondering how to get a backup without mysqldump, but it seems there's a perl script that can help me (see edit above)

Comment: Rebooting my virtual-machine has helped for me